# Magento 2 - How to reindex one product

Tags: magento2, product, reindex, indexing

I have issue with missing some products on frontend.
I noticed that reindexig catalog_product_category is fixing this issue.
In observer triggered after import I just add reindexing script:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $productId = $observer->getEvent()->getId();
    $this->getIndexer(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category::INDEXER_ID)->reindexRow($productId);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param string $indexerId
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterface
 */
protected function getIndexer($indexerId)
{
    return $this->indexerFactory->create()->load($indexerId);
}
```

Importing script changes products one by one.
Unfortunately this doesn't works fine. However if I do:

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $this->getIndexer(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category::INDEXER_ID)->reindexAll();
    return $this;
}
```

it will reindex all catalog_product_category for every imported product.
Is it possible to reindex one product?
Generally first script should works fine, but it doesn't - all imported products are missing.

Comment: can you add the path for indexerFactory ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like

```
    public function reindexByProductsIds($productIds, $indexLists)
    {
        foreach($indexLists as $indexList) {
            $categoryIndexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get($indexList);
            if (!$categoryIndexer->isScheduled()) {
                $categoryIndexer->reindexList(array_unique($productIds));
            }
      }
}
```

where $indexLists is an array like ['catalog_product_category', 'catalog_product_attribute']

Comment: Please notice that reindexRow() at the end will call the same function as reindexList(). One difference is that reindexRow makes array from one product Id before call it.

Comment: Indeed, for your product you can use reindexRow instead of reindexList.

Comment: Exactly, but there is still a problem and I dont know how can I debug it. Add logs deeply into indexer? It happens on production only.

Comment: Have you got some log yet or nothing ? If not, yes you can add some deeply.

Comment: in your example which class are instantiated in $this->indexerRegistry? I used Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory in my case but i want to try also your solution

Comment: I think my IndexRegistry was `Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry`

Comment: This can be helpful - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/355023/45519