# Magento 2 how to run reindex for single product or some cart line products

Tags: product, cart, product-collection, reindex, indexing

Is there any way in magento to achieve to reindex only single product or some items.

I have a inventory existing /update call on `product page load` and `cart page` load.

Right now doing indexing for all catalog on product page and cart page which is not feasible way.

Any way that can be done get this done?

Comment: How many products you have?

Comment: 50k simple products.

Comment: Ahh then update on save should not be feasible

Comment: However set cron properly it should update indexer as soon as any value changes.

Comment: Which version of magento you are using?

Comment: M2.2.5 cron is already there, but this is double check for inventory on website

Comment: then you you can add cron for only catalog inventory

Comment: that will re-index only inventory

Comment: Every 4 minute cron is there for stock update receive from other third party.

Comment: cron should like this `php MAGENTO_ROOT/bin/magento indexer:reindex cataloginventory_stock`

Comment: My question for single product and some products. I m already aware of catalog index

Comment: I had only above solution however maybe someone else have your specific product solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source / Credit / Main  article - [How to Magento 2 Reindex one Product Programmatically?](https://dolphinwebsolution.com/how-to-magento-2-reindex-one-product-programmatically)

---

### Adding code for reference

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
 
require '../app/bootstrap.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$childIds = $objectManager->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')->getChildrenIds('371009');//get configurable child item
$productIds = $childIds[0]; 
 
//$productIds = ['25206']; //pass product id
//list of indexers
$indexLists = ['catalog_category_product', 'catalog_product_category', 'catalog_product_attribute', 'cataloginventory_stock', 'inventory', 'catalogsearch_fulltext', 'catalog_product_price', 'catalogrule_product', 'catalogrule_rule'];
 
foreach ($indexLists as $indexList) {
    $categoryIndexer = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexList);
 
    if (!$categoryIndexer->isScheduled()) {
    try {
        $categoryIndexer->reindexList(array_unique($productIds));
        echo $indexList . '<br>';
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
}
```